# How do I share data between iOS app and today view extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to show the persons name in the today view extension; but I can't seem to do this. I've watched so many YouTube video's but they never helped. So if you can, I want you to answer this.

How the app works: You type your name inside the app. And the it will show in the today view extension.

About the app: I have a text field and button. The textfield is the persons name and the button is the save the name.

I want to show the name in the today extension.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add the group to the entitlements/capabilities.

1. Go to the capabilities tab of the app's target
2. Enable App Groups
3. Create a new app group, entitled something appropriate. It must start with group..
4. Let Xcode go through the process of creating this group for you.

Save data to NSUserDefaults with group ID and use it in your extension.

From Apple's App Extension Guide :

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

In the main app, save person name:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "your group ID")
defaults!.set("person name", forKey: "key for person name")
defaults!.synchronize()
```

In the extension, you can use saved person name:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "your group ID")
let savedPersonName = defaults!.string(forKey: "key for person name")
```

Comment: I'm using Xcode 11.4.1 so I don't see the enable option. But, if I click the add button on the top, I see app groups. Even if I enable it, what do I do

Comment: Save persons name to UserDefaults :

Comment: Retrieve persons name :

Comment: It would be much better if you could edit your answer and put these comments in your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just a quick notice as I too have missed it**

In order to get it working create the group on app target
and then on Today's target add Group Capability as well and tick the one just created from the main app's target (it should be listed)

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example of today extension in this example, I am only showing and updating the user name [image]

this my today extension storyboard image 
and today-view-Controller code is:

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

    @IBOutlet weak var lnameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let name = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.ahmad.widget")?.value(forKey: "name"){

            lnameLabel.text = name as? String
        }
        else{
            lnameLabel.text = "Wait..."
        }
    }

    func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    }

}
```

I create a storyboard and add a button in this than on his button action I update the user name on today extension

code of viewController is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    @IBAction func SetNameOnWigetAction(_ sender: Any) {

        nameLabel.text = nameTextfield.text
        UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.ahmad.widget")?.setValue(nameTextfield.text, forKey: "name")
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, but which bundle ID do I use? The apps or the today extension

Comment: UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.ahmad.widget")?.setValue(nameTextfield.text, forKey: "name")

here "group.com.ahmad.widget" this is not the App ID or Today Extension ID it's just a unique Id you can change this as you want But he will be same when you get value from the observer

Comment: here is the video link bro chill
How can add a widget for an app
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skbWSQlcN5k

Comment: Okay, I just tested the project but it always shows "waiting...". Should I used UserDeafualts to save the name?

Comment: I've seen that video but my label in the today view shows error

Comment: How do I fix it saying waiting?

Comment: Ok but how do I fix the error of the label showing waiting...

Comment: I think you cannot set the name into user default in the main view controller

Comment: wait I will send you the complete project example them you easily understand what's going on

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: Wait, how are you gonna send me the project?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jX7Mr7QEPy13hWcutoNyjoUxaBKqS8qB?usp=sharing

please check this

Comment: It still shows waiting in my app. I copied and pasted your code but it's not working

Comment: Should I give you my project files so you could modify it?

Comment: yes why not
send me your project I will see what is the error

Comment: Here is the files

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10YAavCGlMHZCGskiEp_dtkViV1YIkso1/view?usp=sharing